# Google Analytics version 3 - How to apply it correctly?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've added google analytics to my app with the intention of obtaining information about the screens you and send custom events.

I am obtained duplicate content ...
Also I get different results:
**"com.package.app.MainScreen"** - 300 views
and
**"Main Screen"** - 200 views

**I am interested to get only follow up with the custom name of the activity and not the package. And in any case, because both show different results?**

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity {
private static final String GA_PROPERTY_ID = "UA-12345678-9"; 
private static final String SCREEN_LABEL = "Main Screen";
Tracker mTracker;
EasyTracker easyTracker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);

    mTracker = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).getTracker(GA_PROPERTY_ID);
    mTracker.set(Fields.SCREEN_NAME, SCREEN_LABEL); // For Custom Name from activity
    mTracker.send(MapBuilder.createAppView().build());

    easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(this); //  Analytics Events
    ...
    easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("MainScreen", "Play", category.get(1), null).build()); //AnalyticsEvents
    ...


}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);
}
```

}

And **analytics.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">
      <!--Replace placeholder ID with your tracking ID-->
      <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-12345678-9</string>
      <!--Enable automatic activity tracking-->
      <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
      <!--Enable automatic exception tracking-->
      <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
    </resources>
```

[Google Analytics Dev Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 separate tracking instances, 2 in the onCreate() and also one in the onStart()/onStop(). I would recommend removing both of them from the onCreate() and just keeping the EasyTracker in the onStart()/noNstop() that way you won't get redundant data, but still get session lengths.

To have custom names for the EasyTracker tracked Activities, you can set them in your `analytics.xml` by adding the following fields as such:

```
<-- Enable automatic Activity measurement -->
<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>

<-- The screen names that will appear in reports -->
<string name="com.example.app.BaseActivity">Home</string>
<string name="com.example.app.PrefsActivity">Preferences</string>
```

Here is an onClick(View) with the EasyTracker to send up UI events:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    String action = "";
    switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnWeb:
        getSherlockActivity().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sponsor.getWebsite())));
        action = "Website";
        break;
    case R.id.btnPhone:
        getSherlockActivity().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("tel:" + PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(sponsor.getPhone()))));
        action = "Phone";
        break;
    }

      EasyTracker easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(getSherlockActivity());
      if (easyTracker != null) {
          easyTracker.send(MapBuilder
              .createEvent("ui_action",
                           "sponsor_page",
                           title + ": " + sponsor.getName() + " - " + action,
                           null)
              .build()
          );
      }
}
```

Comment: But that way, I can not send events or even get a custom name for the activity.

Comment: @ephramd Then you wouldn't want to use the EasyTracker, but you would still want to have a Tracker in the onStart()/onStop(). You would use a different tracker for events on a individual basis. I'll post some code...